# How to change the angular material form input style into normal input?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I want to change the existing input lines into normal input boxes. How do i accomplish that? I'm using Angular Material 6.4.1

Comment: Use a normal input \o/

Comment: remove `matInput` from your `<input>` ?

Comment: Did you mean _filled text fields_?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean *normal input boxes* as [*filled text fields*](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#filled-text-field), this can be done by setting the `appearance` property of the form field element to `fill` for a filled text field:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="email">
  <!-- ... -->
</mat-form-field>
<!-- ... -->
```

---

> See also:
>
> - [Angular Material docs covering the form field appearance variants](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants)
> - [Angular Material form field API for `MatFormField`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormField)